# Blazor auth with IdentityServer, enable registration

Tags: blazor, identityserver4, blazor-webassembly

I'm developing one project that is componsed by a IDP with IdentityServer, and a Blazor client.

Currently the project is allowed to login with the following code:

**Client Program.cs**

```cs
builder.Services.AddOidcAuthentication(opt => 
{
    builder.Configuration.Bind("oidc", opt.ProviderOptions);
});
```

**appSettings**

```json
  "oidc": {
    "Authority": "https://localhost:44395/",
    "ClientId": "blazor-client",
    "DefaultScopes": [
      "openid",
      "profile"      
    ],
    "RedirectUri": "https://localhost:44305/authentication/login-callback",
    "PostLogoutRedirectUri": "https://localhost:44305/authentication/logout-callback",
    "ResponseType": "code"
  }
```

**Authentication page**

```cs
@page "/authentication/{action}"
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication
<RemoteAuthenticatorView Action="@Action" />

@code {
    [Parameter] public string Action { get; set; }
}
```

Once configured the client in the IDP, and navigating through /authentication/login everything works, the client redirects to Account/Login in IDP, and once authenticated it redirect back to the client as expected.

The problem I have is once I started to redirect to the register action in IDP.

Having a look on RemoteAuthenticatorView seems to be prepared for redirecting to a external register (In my case in Account/Register) however if I try to navigate through /authentication/register from my Blazor client, an error is shown without more information:

> Registration is not supported.

Please note that the view and action for Registration is already created and it works from the IDP project.

I have reviewed the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/standalone-with-authentication-library?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio) from MSDN but I can't find clear information about how it has to be configured to enable this redirection to the registration view.

Could someone give me some light on what needs to be added, or if for some reason it is not possible in this scenario?

Many thanks

Comment: Have a look at ASP.NET Core Identity: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity

Comment: Hi! currently I'm managing this with ASPNET Core Identity. I mean, user store is with it, and it works, the problem that I have it's trying to connect/redirect properly from a Blazor WASM, how can this link solve my problem? Thanks!